# Addressing a mandatory unavoidable circular dependency in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, circular-dependency

I need perform session timeout from UI side. Below are the steps.

1. On successful login, I start a timeout to display a popup
   **setTimeout(()=>{this.openTimeOutDialog();},expTime);**
2. After 1 hour, the timeout popup appears which asks user either to logout or stay connected. and I set another timeout to here for 5 minutes within which the user should click on stayconnected else they will be logged out.
   **setTimeout (()=>{this.logout();}, time);**
3. If the user clicks on stay connected, I need to call this first setTimeout again from the TimeOutDialog component which is creating a circular dependency. i.e. when user clicks on stay connected, a call will go to the first setTimeout and then from there again the same TimeOutDialog will be called.
   I tried various ways but this dependency exists.
   I donot see a way to avoid this circular dependency. Need help fixing this. Thanks!
   Here is my code

   // Login Service Code

````
    Import {TimeOutDialog} from './../../timeout/timeout.component';
    Import {LogoutService} from './../logout.service';
    Import{MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
    
    constructor(private logoutService: LogoutService, public dialog: MatDialog ){}
    
    export class LoginService{
    
    login(uid, pwd){
    .........
    .........
    this.setSessionTimer(expTime);
    }
    
    setSessionTimer(expTime){
    setTimeout(()=>{this.openTimeOutDialog();},expTime);
    }
    
    openTimeOutDialog(){
    setTimeout (()=>{this.logoutService.logout();}, time);
    this.dialog.open(timeoutDialog, {width: '500px'});
    }
    ```


//Logout Service code

    ```
    Export class LogoutService{
    ```logout(){
    ............
    ............
    }
    }
       

//Dialog Component code
````

```
Import {LoginService}from './../../services/login.service;
Import {LogoutService}from './../../services/logout.service;
Import {MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

constructor(private logoutService: LogoutService, private loginService: LoginService ){}

Export TimeOutDialog{
stayConnected(){
this.loginService.setSessionTimer(expTime);
}

logout(){
this.logoutService.logout();
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [rxjs's `Observables`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview). They are the real endorsed way of dealing with asynchronous operations like this inside of Angular.

Comment: you cannot have circular references period.  In any language an "observer pattern" (or "events" as they're often called) is the common solution to this, but it is a bit of a deep rabbit hole.  You should post some code that meets the requirements of SO if you want further help.

Comment: what dialogs you are using?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Hi I am using Angular material dialog

Comment: @JamieMarshall I have included my code above

Comment: if @AshotAleqsanyan 's answer doesn't work, maybe you can tell me what you're actually seeing on screen when this executes.  Does the model pop up with several copies?  Do you just end up with lots of timers?  Does the program hang in an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks guys! I will try this on Monday and update here by eod.

Comment: Hi guys sorry for the delay. I had some other urgent commitment so couldnt try this previously but did that yesterday and it worked. Thanks so much. I had some more glitches but i was able to fix those after including clearTimeout. That was a great help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that case you can listen the dialog close and start the timer in case of necessary

```
 openTimeOutDialog(){
    setTimeout (()=>{this.logoutService.logout();}, time);
    this.dialog.open(
      timeoutDialog, 
      {width: '500px'}
    )
    .afterClosed()
    .subsribe(
       response => { if(response.startSession) {this. setSessionTimer() } }
    )

 }
```

where the response of `afterClosed` meethod comes from the dialog

like this
Modal.component.ts

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public modalRef: MatDialogRef<ModalComponent, ModalOutputData>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DefaultModalInputData
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data, 'data');
  }

  /**
   * close dialog and continue
   *
   * @param null
   *
   * @return `void`
   */
  onContinue() {
    this.modalRef.close({ startSession: true }); 
  }
}
```